# Setting a default value on NULL columns from LEFT JOIN and filtering using WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a table of items and I have a separate table containing the individual purchases of each item. Not every item has been purchased. I am selecting the purchase count and joining it with the items table with a statement similar to the following:

```
SELECT items.name, purchases_count
FROM `items` 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT sales.item_name, SUM(unit_sales) AS purchases_count 
        FROM sales GROUP BY item_name) sales ON sales.item_name = items.uid
```

This results in data similar to:

```
+------+-----------------+
| name | purchases_count |
|------+-----------------+
| Shoe | 12              |
| Belt | NULL            |
+------+-----------------+
```

My problem arises when I want to filter this result on the `purchases_count`. If I use `WHERE purchases_count < 10` or something similar, items with no sales record at all (i.e. those with a `NULL` value) are excluded from the search.

I have attempted to use `COALESCE(purchases_count,0) AS purchases_count` which does correctly set `NULL` records to 0, but they are still not appearing when using `WHERE`. I suspect the `COALESCE` is happening after the `WHERE`.

I would like to be able to filter on this number using `WHERE` and include `NULL` results (as zeros) if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: `alias` of left join table is same as table name, is it good practice??

Comment: The SQL query has been simplified just to focus the question, the actual SQL is different to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aliases don't generally apply in the `WHERE` clause - try `COALESCE(purchases_count,0) AS purchases_count_2` with `where purchases_count_2 < 10` to see what I mean.

`where COALESCE(purchases_count,0) < 10` should work.

Comment: Using purchases_count_2 won't work, it's the same issue as using COALESCE on the normal purchases_count — it's not recognised in the WHERE clause. `WHERE COALESCE(purchases_count,0) < 10` does work, but I'd rather find a way to not have to wrap the COALESCE here. Might be the best option for now though, thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this works on MySQL but you could use a subquery: `select * from (select ... coalesce(purchases_count,0) as purchases_count ...) where purchases_count < 10`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of counting the purchases in a separate query, just group the main query instead. To filter on the count, put that in a `having` caluse:

```
select i.name, coalesce(sum(s.unit_sales), 0) as purchases_count
from items i
left join sales s on s.item_name = i.uid
group by i.name
having purchases_count < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
WHERE (purchases_count < 10) OR (purchases_count IS NULL)
```

of course, you'd still be left with null values, but you can still try the COALESCE option to turn those nulls into zeroes for later usage.

Comment: The idea is that I want to be able to apply arbitrary filters to these numbers, so I don't want the NULLs being returned when I'm looking for purchases_count > 6 for example, which would be the case using this.

Answer (score 1):

have u try this

```
SELECT items.name, IFNULL(purchases_count,0)
FROM `items` 
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT item_name, SUM(unit_sales) AS purchases_count 
            FROM sales GROUP BY item_name
           ) s ON s.item_name = items.uid
GROUP BY items.name
HAVING purchases_count >10
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect. HAVING only applies when using GROUP BY.

Comment: The COALESCE would do nothing here anyway as there is no NULL data to COALESCE to zero in the subquery to begin with.

Comment: see there is `Group BY` in `left join`

Comment: @James: having can be used without grouping. It's for applying where-style clauses to the results of aggregate functions, but doesn't HAVE to be done aggregate results. `select x from y where x='1'` and `select x from y having x='1'` are completely equivalent, but the whereclause filters at the row level and having filters at the results level, immediately before the results get sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE is correct way, but you should not use WHERE, try :-

```
HAVING purchases_count<=10
```

Comment: This is completely incorrect. HAVING only applies when using GROUP BY.

Comment: The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can add a where clause like this:

```
 WHERE purchases_count < 10 OR purchases_count is NULL
```